# clisecure v 6.0 - renaming method calls and reflection

Tags: c#, .net, security, obfuscation, command-line-interface

Renaming methods calls making the reflection using unavaiable. Could somebody share a trick to protect specified calls from renaming in CliSecure v6.0?

Thanks in advance.

C.H.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by checking is obfuscated, and sending back to client normal or obfuscated call.